# dynamically changing the numbers in the cell based on the the user input

Tags: vba, excel

I Have a excel sheet under column a I have say 10 values
cell A1 = 1, cell A2 = 2, cell A3 = 3.....cell A10 = 10
Now suppose a user changes the value in cell A3. say cell A3 = 1
so now all the other values should change dynamically
say A1 will change to 2, A2 will change 3, A3 is already 1, A4 will change to 4 and so on...
similarly if any other values changes the rest values should be arranged dynamically..keeping only the unique 10 values. no values should be repeated.

I have tried achieving this by copying the values but unable to do so.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2MX4.png)

Comment: Probably want to use an array with `worksheet_change`.

Comment: can you just provide me a coding example keeping in mind the as per the above situation

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Try this Change event for the worksheet ...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myVal As Variant
    Dim iCount As Long

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    myVal = Target.Value
    iCount = 1
    For Each cell In myRange
        If Intersect(Target, cell) Is Nothing Then
            If iCount = myVal Then
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
            cell.Value = iCount
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
    Next cell


    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

... since you asked for a revision. This uses "a_" in front of the number to show that it's auto generated and "u_" to show it's user generated.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim myVal As Variant
    Dim iCount As Long
    Dim usedString As String
    Dim BypassChange As Boolean

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myRange As Range

' if the changed range is not of interest, bail out
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

' get setup for the work
    Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

' usedString will be used to determine if a number has already be set by the user
    usedString = " "
    For Each cell In myRange
        If Left(cell.Value, 2) = "u_" Then
            usedString = usedString & "-" & Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 2) & "-"
        End If
    Next cell

' check to make sure the user hasn't specified the same number twice. If he has
' BypassChange will make sure the change gets removed later.
    myVal = Target.Value
    If InStr(usedString, "-" & myVal & "-") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Value already specified -> " & myVal
        BypassChange = True
    End If

' here's the work
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    iCount = 1
    For Each cell In myRange
        If Intersect(Target, cell) Is Nothing Or BypassChange Then
            If Left(cell.Value, 2) <> "u_" Then
                If iCount = myVal Then
                    iCount = iCount + 1
                End If
                Do While InStr(usedString, "-" & iCount & "-") > 0
                    iCount = iCount + 1
                Loop
                cell.Value = "a_" & iCount
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
        Else
            cell.Value = "u_" & myVal
            usedString = usedString & "-" & Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 2) & "-"
        End If
    Next cell

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: one more twist if can help me with the same as well..now suppose the value in a5 is changed to 1 and so all the other number changes which is working fine...now if i change the value of cell a7 to say 2 then in this case a1 will be 3 , a2 will be 4, a3 will be 5, a4 will be 6, a5 is already 1, a6 will be 7, a7 will be 2 as the user chaged the value, a8 will be 8..a9 will be 9 and so on...so if any other value chages it should not affect the value which is already changed.

Comment: To do what you are asking, you need some means to determine which values are "locked" and which values are "dynamic". You could do this with another column and code to manage it, you might do it with a persistent array, or you may code the values differently - e.g instead of 1-10, you might use text. For example a_1 is automatically generated value and u_1 is user generated value.

Comment: so u mean i can have a seperate database of the orignal values and then whenever any value changes it must be locked so that there wont be any changes to that value. and only the value which remained unchanged will change based on the user input..can you provide a coding example of the same if u can or if u have time?

Comment: @RsharkSayyed you should upvote via top left corner of the answer if this helped you. This definitely deserves upvotes.

Comment: Bravo superb work done! Thanks @OldUgly
Yes I did findwindow, but it is showing me when I'll earn 15 reputation then it will be displayed.

Comment: This is what I was looking for..Besides this for the second part of the same which is present in a different sheet. I need a value present in one cell to be replaced with the other as and when the user changes. which means suppose a1 has value "3" and a5 has value "6" ..and if the user change the value of cel a1 to "6" then cell a5 will get value "3" i.e value of cell a1. while the rest of all the value in the remaininf cell will remain unchanged. similarly it will continue as and when the user changes values

Comment: Sounds like a challenge for you, now you have starting material. 8)

Comment: yes I do have and will work on the same..Thanku so much

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a formula saying adding 1 from the next one up

```
A1=1
A2="=A1+1"
A3="=A2+1"
A4="=A3+1"
A5="=A4+1"
A6="=A5+1"
```

[image]

if you copy and paste it should automatically change

am I not understanding your issue properly?

Comment: i dont want to copy and change..the user will enter a value into any of the cell under A column from a1 to a10..suppose a user enters a value say 1 in cell a5...then cell a1 will change to 2 , cell a2 to 3 a3 to 4 a4 to 5 , a5 is already 1 as the user entered it. a6 will be 6 and so on....need to to this via va coding so that the value changes dynamically

Comment: i want it dynamically using vba..the user will enter a value in cloumn a itself.
suppose a user enter value 1 in cell a5...then cell a1 will change to 2, cell a2 to 3, cell a3 to 4,cell a4 to 5, cell a5 is already 1 as entered by user. cell a6 to 6 and so on...so the changes will only be in cell a based on what the user enters in any of the cell in the range of a1 to a10.I hope u got my question

Comment: I miss understood Let me see if I can come up with someone I'll delete my question later on

Comment: ur help will be appreciated..i need to complete this by tomorrow any how..atleast the working example

Comment: Can I ask what this will be used for

Comment: i have a project which i need to complete..its basically setting up the prioties..as in currenty the priority is set from 1 to 10 sequentially..but if the user wants he can chage the priority ans so change in any 1 value will cause the other value to change..this is just an example...so that i can atleast get a start